# How can I correctly set a SessionAttribute into a Spring MVC Controller class and retrieve and use it into another Controller class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following problem.

Into an **home() controller method defined into a class named **HomeController** I retrieve an object using a service. This object have to be put as **Session Attribute** so it can be used from other methods in other controller classes.

So I have done in this way:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"progettoSelezionato"})
@PropertySource("classpath:messages.properties")
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);
    private @Autowired HomeService homeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {

        List<Tid023Intervento> listaInterventi = homeService.getListaInterventiRUP(18);

        model.addAttribute("progettoSelezionato", listaInterventi.get(0));

        model.addAttribute("listaProgettiRUP", listaInterventi);//TODO

        return "home";
    }
}
```

As you can see I have used this annotation on the class level:

```
@SessionAttributes({"progettoSelezionato"})
```

and then I put this object by:

```
model.addAttribute("progettoSelezionato", listaInterventi.get(0));
```

I am not sure that this is correct because, from what I know, this put the retrieved **listaInterventi.get(0)** object into the model with the voice **progettoSelezionato**. So I am absolutly not sure that it is putted as **SessionAttributes**.

Then, after that this object is putted as **SessionAttriibute** I have to retrieve and use if from a **gestioneDatiContabiliEnte()** method defined into another controller class, so I am doing in this way:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"progettoSelezionato"})
@PropertySource("classpath:messages.properties")
public class GestioneDatiContabiliEnteController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/gestioneDatiContabiliEnte", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String gestioneDatiContabiliEnte(Model model) {

        System.out.println("INTO gestioneDatiContabiliEnte()");
        System.out.println("PROGETTO SELEZIONATO: " + progettoSelezionato);
        return "gestioneDatiContabiliEnte/gestioneDatiContabiliEnte";
    }

}
```

But it seems can't work because Eclipse sign me error on this line:

```
System.out.println("PROGETTO SELEZIONATO: " + progettoSelezionato);
```

The error is: **progettoSelezionato cannot be resolved to a variable**.

How can I correctly put the **listaInterventi.get(0)** as **SessionAttribute** into my **HomeController**? And how can I retrieve and use it into the **gestioneDatiContabiliEnte()** method defined into my **GestioneDatiContabiliEnteController** class?

Comment: Although you could abuse `@SessionAttributes` for that, that isn't what it is intended for. Its intended use is for the same controller store an object in the session. If you want to set it in the session just add `HttpSession` to your method signature and put it in yourself. And where you need it, inject the session and obtain it. Note in Spring 4.3 there is a `@SessionAttribute` annotation coming next to the `@RequestParam` annotation to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Soled by myself, I can access to this object by:

```
model.asMap().get("progettoSelezionato");
```